# How to fill out the SD card using adb push

Tags: android, batch-file, copy, push, adb

I need to fill out the SD card (0kb as free space), so, I am using the following batch to copy file "Maroon.file" (25mb) with different names on the sdcard (Maroon_1.file, Maroon_2.file, ...)

```
set counter=0
:COPYSMALLFILES
set /a counter=%counter% + 1
adb push Maroon.file /sdcard/Download/Maroon_%counter%.file | findstr /L "failed" |  findstr /C:"failed to" 
echo %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==1 (
    GOTO COPYSMALLFILES
)
```

When the SD card has no more memory to copy any other file the `adb push` gives this message "`failed to copy 'Maroon.file' to '/sdcard/Download/Maroon_4.file': No space left on device`", I am trying to catch that message with the `findstr` commands searching by the word "`failed`", I have tested that command (`findstr`) and works fine separated but with the `adb push` command It does not work. Someone has any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does the error message still display even though you pipe to findstr?

If so, then the error is probably being written out onto the **stderr** (2) stream instead of the **stdout** (1) stream.  Add this stream redirect to your command. `2>&1`

`adb push Maroon.file /sdcard/Download/Maroon_%counter%.file` **`2>&1`** `| findstr /L "failed" |  findstr /C:"failed to"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got exactly what you need; how about the grep command?